# Finding Cirlcles in Eye or pupil using HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm unable to draw the circles on image. Can u check it out. The problem was at drawing circles where i'm unable to retrieve the radius and center of the circle's found on the image.
Thanks in advance.

Code:(Python)

```
import cv,cv2
import numpy as np

def Eyes_Detect(frame):
    cas = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:\opencv2.4.10\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_eye.xml")
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    x=1.1
    res=cas.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=x,minNeighbors=2,minSize=(20,50),flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)
    while len(res)>2:
        x+=0.1
        res=cas.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=x,minNeighbors=2,minSize=(20,50),flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)
    if len(res)<2:
        return (False,[])
    else:
        return (True,res)

def Find_Canny_Edges(frame):
    res = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200)
    return res

def Find_Circles(frame):
    cv.Smooth(frame,frame,cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 7,7)
    storage=cv.CreateMat(frame.width, 1, cv.CV_32FC3)
    cv.HoughCircles(frame,storage,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,100.0,30,150,100,140)
    return storage

def Draw_Circles(image,storage):
    for circle in storage:
        radius = circle[2]
        center = (circle[0], circle[1])
        cv.Circle(image, center, radius, (0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0)
    return image
# Main    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,1280)
cap.set(4,720)
ct=1
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    result = Eyes_Detect(frame)
    if result[0]==True:
        result = Find_Canny_Edges(gray)
        cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",result)
        result = cv.LoadImage('image.jpg',0)
        result = Find_Circles(result)
        result = Draw_Circles(frame,result)
        cv2.imshow("Output",result)
        if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why are you writing the frame to file, then reloading that frame? That's really unnecessary.  What do you mean you're "unable" to retrieve the radius and centre?

Comment: Actually upto finding canny edges was done with cv2 module.. usually which will work on normal numpy arrays. But while working with cv Hough Circles function we need to send image matrix as cvMat format (something which i'm not familiar with).. Just print the data type of result after this line " result = cv.LoadImage('image.jpg',0) " .... you will see its data type. or else you can suggest some other way to retrieve the co-ordinates r(radius),x,y ; where (x,y) is center . . .

Comment: I highly advise against saving an intermediate image... ESPECIALLY using JPEG compression as you will get compression artifacts in order to compress the image to save space.  Compressing an image and loading it in again is like taking a photocopy of a photocopy.  I also don't understand why you're using `cv` when `cv2` is more easier to use?

Comment: Also, what version of OpenCV are you using?  Do `import cv2`, `cv2.__version__` in the Python Command Prompt and tell me what you get.

Comment: Yes its 2.4.10 . I didn't find exactly any other methods in cv2 to retrieve the circles data using houghCircles method. I gone through its arguments syntax as well (cv2.HoughCirlces). When I print the result its like a matrix like 4354X1 . 4354 is the width of the image which I have taken as size of the storage array(numpy) empty one to store the method results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try their [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html). I extract the example code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

if circles is None:
   print "No circles found"
else:
   circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
   for i in circles[0,:]:
      # draw the outer circle
      cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
      # draw the center of the circle
      cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

   cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this code.. It showing error like there is no module named cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT in cv2.. kind off...

Comment: @AdityaByreddy: Sorry for the typo. I just edited my code. The parameter should be read: cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT. Please try again.

Comment: Yeah its working. Thank you @Ha Dang. Can I omit that cv2.cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT. what i mean to say is I will do canny edge detection first which will results in edges, its like binary image right. So then if we apply gradient again. hope you got my point.

Comment: @AdityaByreddy: Please accept the answer if it works for you. About your question in the comment, my answer is "yes, why not".

Comment: Tutorial link broken